# Screenscraping - going down through several tag names to a class name

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Having a hard time getting to the blue line to give it a value (it's a text box):

[image: img1]

Here is my current attempt to reach it - code is returning the typical `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

```
IE.Document.GetElementById("main"). _
GetElementsByTagName("div")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("div")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("div")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("table")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("tbody")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("tr")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("td")(0). _
GetElementsByClassName("textbox125 PatientID")(0).Value = patientid
```

It's been a little while since I've done screenscraping, I'm guessing I have an extra tag name in there or I'm on the wrong item number for one of the tags... And before anyone asks, I don't really like query selector and I prefer to write out my scraping this way :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#main .textbox125.PatientID")
```

This targets the parent id of `main` and the target element class `.textbox125 PatientID`. As compound class names are not allowed an additional `.` is required to remove whitespace.

If you don't want to use querySelector, using only what is visible, a guess would be using tag name and go for:

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
```

Remember:

You can always right click to get a basic selector/xpath on an element

[image]

And, the longer the path you use the more fragile your method becomes.

---

Longer path:

From what I can see you want the **second** `td` tag i.e. index 1 and then repeat that with the child `input` tags. This is based on what is visible! Really need the actual HTML to test with please as I am not confident with the viability of this.

```
IE.Document.GetElementById("main"). _
GetElementsByTagName("div")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("div")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("div")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("table")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("tbody")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("tr")(0). _
GetElementsByTagName("td")(1). _
GetElementsByTagName("input")(1).Value = patientid
```

Comment: So the query selector really does work like a charm, I've just never been able to figure it out... Do you have any good resources for me to read up on it a bit more? Going off of what's visible has always worked for me in the past...

Comment: Really great, thanks! I've already been able to add the next couple of steps with ease using the selector, I guess my main concern is what if I don't have an ID element to build off of (last question)?

Comment: That is where CSS selectors are brilliant. Much more versatile.  I added an id selector in but there are a ton of different ways to get to elements without id. What else are you after? Have a look at those links as well as they show you some of the different selector types and combination methods. You can select by relative position, tag, class, attribute, id.....

Comment: You really have become the go-to guy when it comes to work using `.querySelector()` @QHarr. Keep it going!!

Comment: Lol...@SIM  Passing on your teachings! Just gutted that VBA supports so little :-(  I was just looking at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Column_combinator) but can only see it ever being useful in CSS direct.

Comment: I hope someday we will be able to use pseudo selectors within vba.

Comment: Me 2. Does python allow for it? I have slacked off on my python stuff :-(

Comment: Yeah, when you use `lxml` library (not every psudo selectors yet). However, `BeautifulSoup` don't.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the help! Luckily this site that I'm working with is really well built, seems to be a nice setup all throughout to work with, so nothing without an ID yet - I'm sure I'll run into something funky soon though...

Comment: @dwirony Then come holler at the dawghaus or post here.

Comment: @QHarr Will do!

Comment: @QHarr Hey those resources are gone and so is the link to the dawghaus - would you mind sharing those again?

Comment: On train but yes will get them to you later today.

Comment: Dhaus link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus

Answer (score 1):

Run only this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim objApp  As Object
    Set objApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objApp.Navigate "www.stackoverflow.com"
    Do While objApp.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim myDocument As Object:  Set myDocument = objApp.Document
    Dim myElement As Object: Set myElement = myDocument.getElementById("footer")

    Stop

End Sub
```

- It stops on the `Stop` line.
- With mouse select the word `myElement`, so it becomes blue.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> and enter the local window.
- In the local window, see the whole tree and replicate it in your code.

[image]

Comment: Huh, I've never seen this before - I'm out of the office now, I'll try this tomorrow and report back...

Comment: Hmm this presents an empty locales window for me... just says "No Variables".

Comment: @dwirony - yeah, I was thinking about something else when I wrote it yesterday. Take a look at the updated answer and change it with your own web resource. The `watch window` is really a great help in cases like this.